# Should I use a single master table in a NoSQL DB (Cosmos)?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, data-modeling

I'm trying to model data in Cosmos DB.
We're trying to keep keys consistent i.e. Country_Id, Category_Id etc., i.e it should be coming from a lookup/master
Since we don't really enforce foreign key constraints in NoSQL, is there merit in bunching all lookups into a single collection i.e. id, type, value, ["other attribs"] e.g. for states, type = "state", name="Texas"?
I've seen people discourage the same pattern on SQL databases (MUCK etc.). Should we use multiple master tables here as well?

Comment: Welcome! As you haven't shown any sample data, typical query examples, etc, there's really no way to answer this objectively. Well, even if you *did* share your data, I'm not sure you'd be able to get an objective answer here. Data modeling is a fairly broad and involved topic, and it'll be very specific to the needs of your app and related queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases you can use a single container to store master or lookup data for your application and use a discriminator property such as "/type" as the partition key for your data.

The benefit is you can keep all this data inside a single container which reduces throughput cost of storing it in individual containers. Additionally, when doing things like hydrating user-interface elements on a page, you can fetch all the data in a single query and use an IN statement in your where clause to fetch only the data you need. (I recommend caching in memory after that initial call so that each user does not require fetching the same data again).

Another thing to keep in mind is that you should look at using Change Feed to maintain any referential integrity between this data and other containers where it is used. For a NoSQL database like Cosmos DB, you often will want to denormalize data. Change Feed can be used to keep that data in sync.

If you are new to Cosmos DB and NoSQL modeling in general, I encourage you to watch this video which will give you a good foundation to start. https://youtu.be/3gEytt-Jops?t=1559

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Your inputs are useful. I appreciate your time.